# prepareForReuse not called in custom cell class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my custom cell (which extends `UITableViewCell`), I have the `prepareForReuse` method and its not called after

```
[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierBody forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

where as

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
```

is being called. Any suggestions what I could possibly be doing wrong?  Correct class instance is being returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

**EDIT** is `prepareForReuse` not called on an initial cell creation/initialization? What should be used on initial creation/initialization if this is so? I have a `UITextView` inside my custom cell that needs to be initialized/sized.

Answer (score 0):

Of course as soon as I edited my original question I remembered about 
`- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder`. 
I think this is the way to go and do all of the initialization there.